# What is the best way to add the latest version of jQuery to a theme?

Tags: 6, javascript

This is just a simple question I have. I'm most interested in seeing what others are doing to use the latest version of jQuery in themes.

The reason for this is that some of the best jQuery plugins I use require much later versions of jQuery than what Drupal comes with.

I have tried the update jquery module but it is not as good for Drupal 6 sites.

Is there another way outside of adding your own version of jQuery. Then once you have it finding and replacing `jQuery` with something like `myQuery` and sticking `myQuery.noConflict()` at the end? And then once this is done rewriting plugins to work with `myQuery`?

Comment: why is the jquery_update module not working for you? is it because the version of jquery is still to old for your purposes?

Comment: this is correct, yes.

Comment: Check the dev branch of jquery_update, it might have a newer version of jQuery available, but might also break core/contrib JavaScript. So if you get errors or missing fields on forms try changing jquery_update's jQuery version to previous ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution is to replace drupal jQuery with the latest jQuery only on the pages where you really need it. If you go on with newest jQuery many of drupal out of the box functionality will be broken.

You can remove native jquery like in the code snippet below only on certain pages that meet your conditions:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $arg, $delta) {
  if(YOUR CONDITION HERE) {
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();
    unset($scripts['core']['PATH TO DRUPAL JQUERY']);
    $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
  }
}
```

to add your newest jquery file you can use drupal_add_js('path to yor newest jquery') function.

Answer (score 0):

This page http://drupal.org/node/1058168 should answer all your questions.  Although Alex has provided probably the best option for Drupal 6 sites.

In Drupal 7, using hook_js_alter() with a separate admin theme is what I would do.